# How do I map text field type of Sql server in EF code first?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have a

**1)** text field type in my Sql server that I would like to map it to Entity framework 4.1 Code First. How can I do that?

**2)** When you declare a string variable in POCO classes, it maps to nvarchar in Sql Server. How it map it to varchar? I am pretty sure my data will always be English and not multilingual.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you not just use `varchar(max)`/`nvarchar(max)` instead of `text`/`ntext`? Then the issue goes away...

Comment: Indeed, text/ntext are obsolete and you should be looking to migrate to the "max" types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
    [MaxLength]
    public string TextProp {get; set;}
}
```

This should create ntext column in Sql Server and not nvarchar.

Comment: ntext has been [deprecated in SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx). You could use varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can specify the mapping type of a column with an attribute -

```
[Column(TypeName = "text")]
public string TextField { get; set; }
```

You could do this for a varchar also, I found this blog post that contains code that swaps the EF default from using nvarchars to varchars, but I haven't tested the code that is supplied in the post -

http://johncoder.com/Post/EFCodeFirstDisableUnicodeforallStringProperties